# When to use stylesheet_pack_tag instead stylesheet_link_tag with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

When creating a new rails project with Rails 6, it creates an application.html.erb with stylesheet_link_tag to load CSS and javascript_pack_tag for javascript files.

Now, rails 6 also provide a stylesheet_pack_tag, so my question is, when to use it? And if we use it, do we need to add all CSS files in app/javascript folder?

What is the best practice to load css, images with rails 6 and webpacker?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use `stylesheet_pack_tag` if you are importing any CSS in Webpack AND if you have enabled `extract_css: true` for any environment in `config/webpacker.yml`.

Given the following directory structure:

```
app/
  javascript/
    packs/
      application.js
    styles/
      site.css
```

And the following code in `application.js`:

```js
import '../styles/site.css'
```

You would use `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>` in your view, i.e., the name of the stylesheet matches the name of the "pack".

At this point, I also recommend renaming `app/javascript` to something like `app/frontend`. So, the key changes in `config/webpacker.yml`:

```yaml
source_path: app/frontend
extract_css: true
```

```
app/
  frontend/
    packs/
      application.js
    styles/
      site.css
```

Comment: Thank you @rossta, but what is the reasoning behind your answer: pack_tag vs link_tag?

Comment: pack_tag is for Webpacker CSS. link_tag is for Sprockets CSS. You can choose one approach or use both; they are distinct bundlers.

Comment: @rossta, you did mention "You would use <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %> in your view, i.e., the name of the stylesheet matches the name of the "pack"." But here "application" refers applicaition.js and there is not application.css or application.scss. So we need to manage CSS using js file only?

Comment: That’s correct. In webpack, CSS and images are imported from your JavaScript files. Your Webpacker config will ensure they are output in the desired format.

Comment: I didn't know it was required to have enabled `extract_css`...game changer @rossta :praying_hands:

Comment: I still get the `Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError` when I take this approach. Anyone else get that when using the stylesheet_pack_tag and solve it?

Comment: My god... I spent a couple of hours debugging why my `.scss` files were not loading. Thank you @rossta!

Answer (score 2):

Just to try to clarify this a little. This is based on my current understanding, which seems to work well enough but still might not be fully accurate.

CSS processed by the asset pipeline gets a `css_link_tag` and css that is imported via a Webpacker javascript bundle is referenced with `css_pack_tag`.

Asset pipeline css is in `app/assets/stylesheets`. Webpack css is in `app/javascripts/wherever_you_want`.

So in webpack, all of the css imported into a javascript bundle is eventually extracted to a servable file that can be referenced via the same name as the js bundle.

So if in `app/javascripts/application.js` you have:

```
import 'app/javascripts/css/one.css'
import 'app/javascripts/css/two.css'
import 'app/javascripts/css/three.css'
```

These will be referenced with

```
css_pack_tag 'application'
```

This comes out looking like this in my deploy logs

```
Entrypoints:
  application (430 KiB)
      css/application-9d82d487.css
      js/application-9f45d7ff735a7a203f28.js
```

It also bears noting, as was mentioned above that this behavior is affected by the `extract_css` setting.

Presumably this is false in `development` by default and true in `production`. One big GOTCHA with this is that, at least in my case, the `css_pack_tag` wasn't actually "required" in development, in the sense that removing it had no effect because it wasn't extracted locally. It still "worked" because the css was loaded in the javascript and seemed to be applied somehow that way. So I removed these tags thinking they were unnecessary before my understanding improved. Unfortunately when I deployed to production on heroku some time later, none of my css was working and it took me a while to figure out why and remember that I had removed these `css_pack_tag` lines.